# Custom Attribute on Aurelia not working

Tags: aurelia, custom-attributes

I am a beginner by Aurelia. I want to program a Custom Attribute as you see here:

square.js:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class SquareCustomAttribute {
  @bindable sideLength;
  @bindable color;

  constructor(element){
    this.element = element;
  }

  sideLengthChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = `${newValue}px`;
  }

  colorChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
  }
}
```

and you can see html in the following:

```
<template>
  <require from="./square"></require>
  <div square="color.bind: squareColor; side-length.bind: squareSize"></div>
</template>
```

I get an error:

> ERROR [app-router] Error: (SystemJS) Unable to dynamically transpile ES module as SystemJS.transpiler set to false.

Could you please help me?

Comment: This is a conflict with your `SquareCustomAttribute` class and your SystemJS transpiler. Is this class written the same way as your others?

Comment: I tried different class. always I get this error

Comment: have you changed something in your build or tasks folder?

Comment: I found it. The problem was  so complicated...I changed the js to ts.

Comment: @user2505235 - This is what I was getting at when asking if this was written in the _same way_ as your other classes. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do what you are trying to do (not purely an attribute) is this:

try this:

square.html

```
<template bindable="sideLength, color">
    <div css.bind="height: ${sideLength}; width: ${sideLength}; background-color: ${color}"/>
</template>
```

now you just use it like this:

[any].html

```
<require from="[path]/[to]/square.html"></require>
.
.
.
<square side-length="50" color="red"></square>
.
.
.
```

There is almost an exact example of this under data binding in the docs:
[Aurelia Docs: Cheat Sheet - Databinding](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5)

Comment: Custom Elements (as you have described) != Custom Attributes (which the OP has asked about)

Comment: realized that after i answered.. I modified my answer to reflect that this is an option to achieve what he is trying, but it is not the attribute route.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an answer so this can be closed.

---

User had an error with his script file causing the transpiler to fail. Changing the file extension from `.js` to `.ts` solved the issue as the TypeScript file could be handled by SystemJS.